# ASP.NET Core MVC alternative to HiddenFor on Edit View

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core-mvc

I use `HiddenFor` on the form of an edit view to make sure that non-editable (by user) data is passed in, and it works great.

But, the value of the hidden field can be modified using the browser console.

For some model property, I was able to use `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]`, but I can't use this attribute for all model properties, because some can be changed depending on user claims.

Example :

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Password)

<input id="Password" name="Password" type="hidden" value="qwerty">
```

It's not really secure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the properties from the ViewModel you use in the edit form. And make sure the data behind the properties is stored on the server in the database. When the user sends the form, just merge the properties from the ViewModel into the database.

Comment: Totally agree with @NineBerry. I cannot think of any good reason to have a hidden input for password.  Once your user is authenticated, you don't need to worry, or are you using your own authentication? In which case you should be hiding a strongly encrypted version of the password.

Comment: Show more context. Using entities in forms directly is asking for trouble; create ViewModels that contain the properties that are allowed to be edited. Then on POST, read the existing entity from the database and manually update the properties that are allowed to be updated.

Comment: There is no way to avoid the client input being modifies. What is your scenario?